how to work around object safe traits in rust
I'm working on writing a toy database implementation in Rust and I can't get around this trait requirement to be object safe. I basically want a way of representing a database table with columns of different types in rust.
This is what my current existing code kind of looks like.
trait Primitive {}
impl Primitive for i32 {}

struct Table {
    value: HashMap<String, Arc<dyn ColType>>,
}

trait ColType {
    fn get_data(&self) -> &Vec<impl Primitive>;
}

struct TableValue<T: Primitive> {
    data: Vec<T>
}

impl <T: Primitive> ColType for TableValue<T> {
    fn get_data(&self) -> &Vec<T> {
        return &self.data;
    }
}


This is a simplified version of how far I have gotten on the data storage side. That being said this code gives the warning ColType cannot be made into an object. Basically I just want this or some similair solution to compile. The requirements are:

I need Primitive to be a trait (implemented on i32's and such). This is because I don't want to use an enum because I'm not sure how I would ensure each value is the same variant and also overhead things.

I don't want to do any Vec<Box<impl Primitive>> stuff because I believe there should be a way to not do something that awful. (why am I making a new pointer per item when a Vec<T> where T: Primitive works!)

The solution must actually be able to store things with (I got something close to working with HashMap<String, Arc<dyn ColType<dyn Primitive>>> by adding a generic argument to ColType<T: Primitive> but this ended up making trait bounds that were impossible to be satisfied.


In my head I should be able to return some heap allocated vec of type Vec<impl ColType + Sized> but that might just be me.

Primative might be a typo of Primitive.

@RichardNeumann oh thanks, I was more so talking about writing code that didn't compile but yeah.

The problem with returning a impl Trait from a method is that the exact type is only determined by the implementors, not the trait. In other words, to know what the concrete return type is, we need to know the concrete type of the implementor. But being able to know the concrete return type is exactly the thing a trait object opts out of. So there cannot be a trait object which would have to be agnostic of the concrete type returned.
You can manually factor out the return type into an associated type and thus make it possible for users to declare that all the trait objects return the same type:
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::collections::HashMap;

trait Primitive {}
impl Primative for i32 {}

struct Table<T: Primitive> {
    value: HashMap<String, Arc<dyn ColType<Item = T>>>,
}

trait ColType {
    type Item: Primitive;
    fn get_data(&self) -> &[Self::Item];
}

struct TableValue<T: Primitive> {
    data: Vec<T>
}

impl <T: Primitive> ColType for TableValue<T> {
    type Item = T;
    fn get_data(&self) -> &[T] {
        &self.data
    }
}

I also switched to returning slices, unless you really need the capacity it's less limiting than returning &Vec<T>.
If you need to be able to store different types in Table you'll have to create a type erased version of ColType and use that:
struct Table {
    value: HashMap<String, Arc<dyn ColTypeErased>>,
}

trait ColTypeErased {
    fn get_data(&self) -> Vec<&dyn Primitive>;
}

impl<T: ColType> ColTypeErased for T {
    fn get_data(&self) -> Vec<&dyn Primitive> {
        ColType::get_data(self).iter().map(|x| x as &dyn Primative).collect()
    }
}

This does require an allocation though.

Okay, I'll try to implement this later. For the type erased version, is there no way of avoiding the allocation to fit the trait bound? Having to make a ref per item in the entire column doesn't seem ideal for a database thing, it's fine if I have to though especially because it's not the actual value being cloned. Also what is the purpose of saying type Item = T;? I've seen this used in different libs but never understood why not just use T.

You need the type Item; in the trait to be able to refer to it in the return type of the method, T is the type it takes for the generic implementation. Of course you could also make the trait generic, but that allows multiple implementations for the same struct which might or might not be what you want.

The difference between an associated type and a generic are more thoroughly explained in When is it appropriate to use an associated type versus a generic type?

Returning a &Vec<impl Primative> in a trait method makes the trait lose object safety, because the compiler has no way of knowing what the layout or alignment is of the heap-allocated items and can therefor not guarantee memory safety during runtime. This has gotten me confused as well a couple of times, because the dyn Trait notation made me think in terms of Liskov's substitution principle, but it actually is about pointers and where we point the CPU. The dyn Trait type is a fat pointer (edit:) trait object, which is !Sized and for which the &dyn Trait is the (Sized) fat pointer; it stores both a pointer to the object (in this case, the type that implements Trait) and a pointer to the vtable. The latter holds all kinds of information about the type, such as where to find the machine code for certain methods, etc. This is very cool and allows for dynamic dispatching; during runtime the vtable is used to point the CPU to the right place where the method we want to call can be found.
On the other hand, the compiler needs to know the exact type returned by get_data for all implementors of the ColType trait, which is not possible here with impl Primative. If it can't know what exact type is returned, it cannot compile a fat pointer to be used for dynamic dispatching because it doesn't know where to point to for the vtable.
I might explain this badly, so I would recommend the book Rust for Rustaceans by Jon Gjengset, it goes into some detail on this topic (and I have read it just last week, this particular chapter, which is why I am answering this question).
Indeed, using Box would fix this, but this comes at a runtime performance penalty. You stated you didn't want to use an enum because of overhead (?) and "I'm not sure how I would ensure each value is the same variant", but isn't that exactly where Rust shines? I mean, pattern matching is one of the coolest things (in my humble opinion ;)).
enum Primative {
    Int(i32),
    // Add more types here if needed, e.g., Float(f64)
}

struct Table {
    value: HashMap<String, Arc<dyn ColType>>,
}

trait ColType {
    fn get_data(&self) -> &Vec<Primative>;
}

struct TableValue {
    data: Vec<Primative>,
}

impl ColType for TableValue {
    fn get_data(&self) -> &Vec<Primative> {
        &self.data
    }
}

Now, the compiler knows the exact type of the return value of the ColType::get_data() trait method, because they are always of type Primative. The only downside on this is memory usage: each item in the &Vec<Primative> is as large as the largest possible variant of Primative.

"The dyn Trait type is a fat pointer" ­– is imprecise or wrong, dyn Trait is unsized so pointers to it Box<dyn Trait>, &dyn Trait are fat pointers, it is not itself a pointer at all.

Fair, I will edit.

If I had an enum for each type like enum Primitive {i32, String ..etc} then a Vec<Primitive> could have different types in the same column which is what I didn't want. The over head I was talking about is storing the enum and the value instead of just the value in the vec. I'm not sure if this makes any sense but yeh.
